# Should I answer a question that I think should be migrated?

Tags: discussion, migration

I've encountered a question that isn't about programming, and suggested it to be migrated to a fellow site (a site that I'm familiar with, and can confidently suggest migration to). However, it's a question that I can answer.

Should I answer it at Stack Overflow (in case the moderators don't think it's unrelated)? Will the question, if it is migrated, be migrated with my answer?

Should I ask (in a comment) for a link to the question on the other site, and say "let's take it there"? (This is what I did in this case; the user just didn't know the other site and was happy to give it a shot there)

Should I forget about it and see if I encounter the question there?

Comment: From the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10250): "It preserves the current revision of the question, all its answers, any comments on any post, as well as most of the votes."

Comment: So I should answer and let the answer be migrated with the question?

Comment: If the migration gets rejected, won't we get stuck with a question that's now much harder to get rid of because it has an answer?

Comment: I would just keep it simple: don't answer questions that do not belong on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you shouldn't answer it.

You should flag the question to be closed. *Maybe* migrated. Answering off-topic questions makes curation harder all around, and sets the wrong expectations for askers.

If you want to post a comment directing the user to the other site, you may do so; but **please**, make sure you are really familiar with the target site topicality rules. Encouraging users to post low-quality questions in other sites is no good.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the last part is not necessary - in the context of my question, it's assumed that I'm familiar enough with the other site (like, familiar enough to give reasonable answers there), so it's a bit irrelevant to warn about bad migrations (and say "close, maybe migrated"). In the example that motivated this question, the off-topic question was well-received on the other site (got one more answer except mine, and both were upvoted).

Comment: @ItamarMushkin This answer is not just for you and even if it would be just for you the fact that you are capable of answering some question does not automatically mean that question would be suitable for other site. It is prudent to warn against migrating poor questions.